# jQuery sortable is very jittery when going past bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have JQuery sortable portlets that are fairly large.  They're in one column and 2 portlets will go beyond the bottom of the page.  When I try to move the portlets, the page jitters very badly and it's hard to see where I'm dropping the portlet. I'm on xp with IE8. Below is my jQuery code.

```
  $('.sort').sortable(
    {
      placeholder: 'portlet-placeholder',
      helper: 'clone',
      cursor: 'move',
      scroll: true,
      handle: ".portlet_topper",
      start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.height());
      }
    }
  )
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Mooseman.  I tried, but JSFiddle dosn't load correctly on IE8.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I created a fiddle using firefox.

Comment: @Mooseman I created a fiddle using firefox.  http://jsfiddle.net/zbKgG/  The jitter happens when the portlets are in the body tag.  It will not happen when the portlets are in another scrollable container, like a frame.